# Gtk3 with Python. Xds protocol: How to implement it?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I've almost finished to write a file manager with python and gtk3. One feature I'd like to add is the ability of archive managers, such as Xarchiver, to drop their content into my program.
A help is appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of drag and drop examples out there for Gtk. After you have that working, post the code that works and ask a more specific question. We are not a free coding site.

Comment: Implementing the xds protocol is not adding drag and drop functionality. My program has already full working drag and drop functionality.

Comment: So... when Xarchiver content gets dropped into your program, what does it look like? A file URI? A binary blob? Please post a more specific example than 'please help me'.

Comment: When Xarchiver, and such programs, drops something into my program nothing appen, because there is no code for Xds.

Comment: Please post some code so we can help. Without seeing your code, we can't study your problem to figure out what is going on. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have no code, because there is not any document in the Gtk3 docs. But the module is this one: https://github.com/frank038/My-File-Manager/blob/master/mfm/iv_module.py .